# git commit and push via batch file on Windows

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I do same task often of committing and pushing changes to remote branch. Being lazy sometimes, I needed to put set of git commands to automatically perform these steps:

```
cd D:\wamp\www\projectName
git checkout dev
git add .
git commit -am "made changes"
git push
pause
```

I also tried:

```
cd D:\wamp\www\projectName
call git checkout dev
call git add .
call git commit -am "made changes"
call git push
pause
```

and

```
cd D:\wamp\www\projectName
git.exe checkout dev
git.exe add .
git.exe commit -am "made changes"
git.exe push
pause
```

Everything works excpet for the final `push` command. Here is output:

```
D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>git checkout dev
Already on 'dev'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.

D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>git add .

D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>git commit -am "made changes"
# On branch dev
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean

D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, for `push`, I am getting:

```
D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I run above commands via git shell itself, everything works fine. I have also added git to Windows Path env variables.

Does anyone have an idea of why it works on git shell and not on batch command ? (even though other commands work but not `push`)

Comment: It probably can't find the ssh agent. Try reading the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable from the git shell and defining that variable in the Windows shell.

Comment: @Barend: Thanks but how do I read and define it ?

Comment: In bash: `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. In cmd: `set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=<value>` (where <value> is whatever port number the echo command returned).

Comment: I ran this at cmd and then ran bat file but still the same result: `set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-AxHhVr4004/agent.4004` and also ran `set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=4004`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For me, by default, Windows executes `.sh` files correctly using Git Bash. So I would write your script as a regular bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /d/wamp/www/projectName
git checkout dev
git add .
git commit -am "made changes"
git push
echo Press Enter...
read
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need, to be able to move code from BBCloud to our development test servers, for stage 1 testing.

To do this, I created a Windows scheduled task:

Under "Actions", I added `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"` in Program/script field (the quotes were required).

In the "Add arguments" field, I entered `c:\path\to\bash script\pull.sh`.

I then completed the Task Scheduler wizard (run frequency, time, etc.).

I then created a bash script, using Nano in Git Bash for Windows containing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /c/path/to/bash script
git pull
```

I would prefer a push to the repository automatically pushing down to the test server, but Pipes, Webhooks, and DeployHQ don't seem to be a solution for our environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one !!

```
cd c://TESTS/path
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
GIT COMMAND GOES HERE
pause
```

Comment: Any rationale behind this?