# Git commit 500 files at a time?

Tags: git, batch-file, git-commit

I have thousands of files that I need to commit but I'm having problems committing them all at once. How can I commit 500 files at a time automatically? The first 500 files should have the commit message "Initial commit part 1", the next 500 should say "Initial commit part 2", and so on. I am using Windows, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in the git documentation about adding a certain number of files. If that's possible, that would be cool.

What you could do is break up your commit into smaller commits, in a couple of different ways that might be more meaningful than an arbitrary number.

You could commit all the files with a certain extension:

```
$ git add *.rb
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   a.rb
        new file:   b.rb
        new file:   y.rb
        new file:   z.rb
```

You could commit files by directory:

```
$ git add first_dir/
```

Or (least meaningful), you could commit all the files from the first half of the alphabet (following up with the second half):

```
$ git add [a-j]*
$ git status                                                                                                                                               
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   a.rb
        new file:   b.rb

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        y.rb
        z.rb
```

There are lots of ways to break up a big commit-- whichever is most logical for your files is what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a command line style commit I recommend looking at janos' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397800/git-commit-and-push-via-batch-file-on-windows). This should do it all in a single commit but it would give you a good base if want them to be separated. This [site](http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2) has a good description of how to use git commands if you do need them to be separate commits.

However if you use the desktop client you should be able to commit all of them at once, I know I have done a single commit of around 1000 files using it.

Comment: Even if the links you referred to answer OP's question, please still include key details or sample code in your answer.

Comment: This would have been a comment if I could have made it one. you need more reputation points to comment than you do to answer, but this was still relevant information that I thought they should have.